# Transformar una variable string a num pero que contiene valores no numéricos STATA

Tags: string, stata

tengo una variable en string que contiene el símbolo < ejemplo :<10, al transformarlo a num con el comando

. destring res_hpv18, gen (res_hpv18num) force

pierdo esos valores que contienen el simbolo menor que. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si pretendes mantener el símbolo < (menor que) no es posible en un valor numérico. En ningún lenguaje de programación.

Comment: como podría trabajar esos valores? colocando el símbolo resta?